# Cant send message from background script to content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send a message from the background script to the content script and it doesn't work, tried multiple solutions I found but none of them work.

I checked that the background and content scripts both work correctly.

I tried to use chrome.runtime\extention and also with message and request...

hope you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

manifest:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ChangeLang",
  "description": "change written text lang",
  "version": "1.3",
  "permissions": ["storage", "contextMenus", "activeTab", "tabs"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Click to change the icon's color"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["changelang.js"]
  }],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  alert("click"); // this alert works
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    "functiontoInvoke": "change"
  });
  alert("click"); // this alert doesn't works
});
```

content.js:

```js
function changeLang() {
  // do something
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, callback) {
  alert("msg"); // never worked
  if (message.functiontoInvoke == "change") {
    changeLang();
  }
});
```

Comment: See the documentation: `browserAction.onClicked` callback is called with just one parameter `tab`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your code setup should look like this:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  alert("click"); // this alert works
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    "functiontoInvoke": "change"
  }, function(response) {
         response.yourFunc();
     });
  alert("click"); // this alert doesn't works
});
```

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, callback) {
  alert("msg"); // never worked
  if (message.functiontoInvoke == "change") {
    callback({yourFunc: changeLang()});
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it but the result was the same. any idea what could go wrong?